# actionbar does not refresh tab selection

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I use a TabSwipeFragment from HoloEverywhere.
In this, I use 3 tabs.

The third tab should not be accessible every time. So I use a TabSelectedListener to check this:

```
this.setOnTabSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
            default:
                break;      
            case 1:
                break;      
            case 2:
                if(PlayerPage.accessable!=1) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
                }
            break;
        }           
    }         
});
```

The Fragment Tab is changed properly, but the Navigation not. The third "PlayerPage" is marked blue, as this is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Runnable tryThis = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
    }

};
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.post(tryThis);
```

Using this method worked.